# Open and Closing brackets appearing round text strings

Tags: objective-c

Why am I always viewing the exclamation marks and open close brackets around my strings in labels like this
("my text")

```
theQuestion.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@ "%@",[currentQuestions objectAtIndex:count]]
```

Comment: It's likely that your strings in the array have them.

Comment: They are stored in the array like this @"my text"

Comment: How are you adding objects to `currentQuestions`?

Answer (score 0):

Objective c comes from an smalltalk which uses the concept of sending messages to objects, the brackets are used to send those messages to the objects. Regarding the exclamation marks in objective c they mean the same as in any other languages which is NOT